# export object with nested properties and values to csv

Tags: c#, properties, csv, export

I am working on a sloution to export a object with nested properties (objects) to a csv file.

here the code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Exports a CSV
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="csv">The CSV data as a string</param>
    /// <param name="filename">The filename for the exported file</param>
    public static void ExportCSV(string csv, string filename)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
        try
        {
            writer.Write(csv);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generate the CSV data as a string using reflection on the objects in the list
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">The generic list</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetCSV<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(GetPropertiesString<T>(list[i]));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }


    public static string GetPropertiesString<T>(T item)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        PropertyInfo[] propInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        for (int i = 0; i <= propInfos.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Type propertyType = propInfos[i].PropertyType;

            if (propertyType != typeof(string) && propertyType != typeof(int) && propertyType != typeof(double) && propertyType != typeof(float) && propertyType != typeof(decimal))
            {
                string test = GetPropertiesString(propertyType);
            }

            sb.Append(propInfos[i].Name);

            if (i < propInfos.Length - 1)
            {
                sb.Append(",");
            }
        }

        sb.AppendLine();

        for (int j = 0; j <= propInfos.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            object o = item.GetType().GetProperty(propInfos[j].Name).GetValue(item, null);

            if (o != null)
            {
                string value = o.ToString();

                //Check if the value contans a comma and place it in quotes if so
                if (value.Contains(","))
                {
                    value = string.Concat("\"", value, "\"");
                }

                //Replace any \r or \n special characters from a new line with a space
                if (value.Contains("\r"))
                {
                    value = value.Replace("\r", " ");
                }
                if (value.Contains("\n"))
                {
                    value = value.Replace("\n", " ");
                }

                sb.Append(value);
            }

            if (j < propInfos.Length - 1)
            {
                sb.Append(",");
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

here my object

```
/// <summary>
/// Basic Person object
/// </summary>
public class Person
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Adress Adress { get; set; }
}

public class Adress
{
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public int PLZ { get; set; }
}
```

the desired csv file format:

```
header: Forename, Surename, Age, Place, PLZ 
values: Joe, Stevens, 30,Town1, 11111
```

I tried to call the method recursive, but then the result of PropertyInfo[] propInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties() has strange items ??

it should be possible to export objects with any nested object deep.

any suggestions?

thanks,
thorsten

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work as expected because you're not calling the method recursively with the right type.

```
GetPropertiesString(propertyType);
```

Should be called like this:

```
dynamic ob = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType);
string test = GetPropertiesString(ob);
```

Comment: hi, thank you. I tried you example without success. how can I check if the property is a nested object. at the moment I check it with a simple if(propertyType != typeof(string)) but I think this is not right or convenient.

Comment: The problem is you are calling GetPropertiesString with a System.Type and that's why your are getting other properties. So replace that code with mine and try stepping with the debugger to see that you'll get nested type properties. You code has several issues though because when you're calling the method recursively you reinstantiate your StringBuilder so you loose previous results